# Why did Alexa awis api stop working for me? 301 moved permanently error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

We use Alexa awis API to pull in data. It seems to have stopped working around January 30th 2019, but we didn't change anything I know about on our end.

Our URL we are requesting is `http://awis.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId={{AWSACESSKEYID}}&Action=TrafficHistory&Range=30&ResponseGroup=History&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Start=20190513&Timestamp=2019-06-11T19%3A38%3A02Z&Url=facebook.com&Signature={{SIGNATURE}}%3D`

and I'm getting a response saying

> "301 Moved Permanently"

I can't find any info on this online. Was there something recently changed?

Comment: `301 Moved Permanently` should be accompanied by a `Location` response header and a new URL or URI.  Is there not one?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The url returned in Location header is the same but just uses https instead of http. When I run this I'm not returned any data besides headers: 
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 15:01:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/xml